# How much bigger than the blade is the rubber allowed to be?

Tags: rules, table-tennis, racket

How much bigger can the rubber be than the blade?

Watching some of the professional table tennis players, I noticed that the rubber attached to their blades, is slightly bigger than the blade itself.

I'm assuming this gives them a slight advantage in terms of extra distance at which their paddle can reach. or is it something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rule 2.04.01 of the ITTF rules and regulations states

> The racket may be of any size, shape or weight but the blade shall be flat and rigid

But Rule 2.4.4 states that the rubber covering

> may extend up to but not beyond the limits of the blade

Answer (score 4):

Although there is no restriction on racket size, shape or weight there are restrictions for rubber covering the racket.

From [ITTF rules and regulations handbook 2017](https://d3mjm6zw6cr45s.cloudfront.net/2016/12/2017_ITTF_Handbook.pdf),

Rule 2.4 The Racket

> 2.4.3 A side of the blade used for striking the ball shall be covered with either
>   ordinary pimpled rubber, with pimples outwards having a total thickness
>   including adhesive of not more than 2.0mm, or sandwich rubber, with pimples
>   inwards or outwards, having a total thickness including adhesive of not more
>   than 4.0mm.

So, rubber can be 2.0mm or 4.0mm thick depending on type of rubber.

> 2.4.4 The covering material shall extend up to but not beyond the limits of the
>   blade, except that the part nearest the handle and gripped by the fingers may
>   be left uncovered or covered with any material.

Rubber attached to professional table tennis players blades, is slightly bigger than the blade itself is not true because rule clearly mention **rubber cannot extend beyond the limits of the blade**.

Other source: [allabouttabletennis.com](http://www.allabouttabletennis.com/table-tennis-rules-and-regulations.html)